# AOT compilation error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: angular, compilation, jit, aot

I am trying to use aot compilation but when the compilation is complete, 
the console prints

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
build.js:1
build.js:1
```

I can't seem to find a proper solution to fix this problem.

This is my rollup-config.js file

```
import rollup      from 'rollup'
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs    from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify      from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'

export default {
  entry: 'src/main.js',
  dest: 'src/build.js', // output a single application bundle
  sourceMap: false,
  format: 'iife',
  onwarn: function(warning) {
    // Skip certain warnings

    // should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
    if ( warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED' ) { return; }

    // console.warn everything else
    console.warn( warning.message );
  },
  plugins: [
      nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
      commonjs({
        include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
      }),
      uglify()
  ]
}
```

And this is my main.aot.ts file

```
  import './polyfills.ts';

  import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
  import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
  import { environment } from './environments/environment';
  import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory';

  if (environment.production) {
      enableProdMode();
  }

  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

And this is my build.js file
    !function(){"use strict";require("./polyfills.ts");var r=require("@angular/platform-browser-dynamic"),e=require("@angular/core"),o=require("./environments/environment"),n=require("../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory");o.environment.production&&e.enableProdMode(),r.platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModuleFactory(n.AppModuleNgFactory)}();

Error is happening here I guess.

And lastly, this is my index.html file

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Among</title>

        <base href="/">

        <script>
            window.module = 'aot';
       </script>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">


    </head>

    <body>
        <app-root>
    Loading...
        </app-root>
    </body>

    <script src="build.js"></script>

    </html>
```

Please help me figure out the solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems, rollup can't correctly handle non-ordinary `imports like import "./polyfills.ts";` and similarly it can handle only imports like these: `import { something } from 'Anything';`

I got a similar error. I removed the statement `import "./polyfills.ts";` from `main.ts`. Instead add the script in the `index.html`. Then recompile the project by the `ngc` compiler `node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json` After that generate your `build.js` file using `node_modules/.bin/rollup -c rollup-config.js`.

Hope this helps. I know this isn't good approach, but it might help.